How to boot ANY usb first?
I want to achieve setup like this:

When I turn on computer with no external usb drive (adata) I want Windows from internal m2 drive (lexar) to boot.*
When I turn on computer with external usb drive (atada) connected I want Windows from that drive (adata) to boot.*

* I do not want to have to manualy pick boot device from (f12) boot menu every time
My mother board is gigabyte b560m d3h with newest bios/uefi called version F12.
Why it is not working:
When I try to setup boot order in boot tab in my bios/uefi I cannot put "usb" option on top, like it was possible years ago with my old computer. I can only sort exact names of existing drives available during this configuration, namely adata and lexar. Whatever order I pick it is working as configured. Both drives are bootable, working correctly, both Windows are launching fine. But when I try to achieve described setup, and put adata drive first, it works until I first unplug it (on shut computer of course) and boot lexar. After that, even if I plug adata back, it never goes back on top of boot list by itself, and from now only lexar boots. How do I achieve desired setup, namely: boot adata if connected, else lexar?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

and which part of my post violates this property?

You could try installing the rEFInd Boot Manager. This has an option to boot any external drives first.
